# Manually grant a Third-Party integration

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-permissions

I'm looking to integrate paypal as a payment gateways for my customers.

I know that to have a third-party permission, you can use RequestPermissions which will return  a token that you can use to ask permission to the user, then you will have the access token and secret token to call Paypal API.

But in my integration I cannot use redirect and callback, so I need my customer to grant permission manually as describe in paypal documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/

My question is, after that my customer add my app in his third-party permission, how can i retrieve the access token / secret token of the user with just his paypal's email ? Or maybe, I don't need it and I can call Paypal Api just with my customer's email?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it manually by logging in to your PayPal account, going into the profile, and then into API Access (or it might say Request API Credentials).

Once in there, you'll choose Grant API Permissions, and then you would enter the API username of the application you're granting permissions for, and then check all the boxes for the permissions you want to grant.

Of course, you'd have your users do this in their accounts and use your API username to grand permissions.

Then you just send their PayPal email address in your API request in the SUBJECT parameter the same you do the un/pw/signature.

Comment: Ok thank you, it's what i thought, but not sure, so in my API request, I just have to put my credentials and the user email who grant me permission as a third party right ?

Comment: Andrew, one more question. To use paypal payment pro, the customer account have to be in US. But do I need to declare my APP in US too ? Or my app can be a non-US and it's the customer who need a account in US. Thanks.

Comment: Just the customer would need to be in US, UK, or Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can go on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/ link and follow the instruction for creating the sandbox account.
After creating account you can get a credential.

Comment: I already have my account and my credential, but what I need is for the customer, when i will make API call on behalf of a third party

Comment: For customer you can create a person account in sandbox not business.

Comment: It is helpful foe you or not?

Comment: Not really sorry, my question wasn't about create account but about what parameter do I need to do the call of paypal API when my customer grant me a third permission of my APP